# How can i read WMI parameters "Data" and "InsertionStrings"?

Tags: delphi, wmi

I try to read the Windows EventLog with WMI -> Win32_NTEventlogFile. I use example code from the Tool "WMI Delphi Code Creator" ([link to WMI tutorial](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/wmi-tasks-using-delphi-%E2%80%93-event-logs/))

```
procedure TEventLogsForm.GetWin32_NTLogEventInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent  Where Logfile="Application"','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    try
      // ????
      if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.Data) then
        Showmessage(IntToStr(Integer(FWbemObject.Data)));// Array of Uint8
      if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.InsertionStrings) then
        Showmessage(String(FWbemObject.InsertionStrings));

    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;

    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

I try to read the parameters "FWbemObject.Data" and "FWbemObject.InsertionStrings". 
But I get the error: **Variant of type (Array Variant) could not be converted to type (OleStr)**

How can to read / display this parameters?

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661), where the vote seems to be "No." . Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to documentation found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 
Data and InsertionString is an array of Byte/String;

Below I used it to iterate them in a for loop, I don't know if make any sense but you could use as an example, to do whatever you need :).

```
procedure GetWin32_NTLogEventInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';
  WbemPassword        ='';
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
  Insertion     : array of String;
  Data          : array of Byte;
  I: integer;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent Where Logfile=''Application''','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    try

      if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.Data) then
      begin
        Data := FWbemObject.Data;
        for I:= VarArrayLowBound(data,1) to VarArrayHighBound(data,1) do
          Showmessage(IntToStr(Data[I]));// Array of Uint8
      end;

      if not VarIsNull(FWbemObject.InsertionStrings) then
      begin
        Insertion := FWbemObject.InsertionStrings;            
        for I:= VarArrayLowBound(Insertion,1) to VarArrayHighBound(Insertion,1) do
          Showmessage(Insertion[I]);
      end;

    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;

    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

There are several examples in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it is writen in VB

Comment: Another option is use the `VarArrayLowBound` and `VarArrayHighBound` methods to find the array bounds.

Comment: @RRUZ +1, could you say which is better in this scenario?

Comment: Always is better use VarArrayLowBound and VarArrayHighBound

Comment: Yes, in some cases the arrays are 1 index based.